# What is the purpose of a Action callback delegate?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, delegates, ienumerator

Hi Folks i am trying to learn more about the Action Delegates in C# but i dont understand it so good. So below i have a Code Example from a Unity C# Project. My Question is. What is the purpose of this "Action doneCallback" parameter  and what does do the "doneCallback.Invoke()" code exactly. Thanks in Advance!

```
public static IEnumerator StartWaiting(
    float time, Action doneCallback, 
    float increment, Action<float> incrementCallback, 
    bool countUp = true)
{
    float timeElapsed = 0f;
    float timeRemaining = time;

    while (timeRemaining > 0f)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(increment);
        timeRemaining -= increment;
        timeElapsed += increment;
        incrementCallback.Invoke(countUp ? timeElapsed : timeRemaining);
    }
    doneCallback.Invoke();
}

public static IEnumerator StartWaiting(float time, 
    Action doneCallback)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    doneCallback.Invoke();
}
```

}

Comment: You can see them as a "pointer" to a method. Invoke executes that method. http://dotnetpattern.com/csharp-action-delegate So basically in your code you can pass any method that has a float parameter (e.g. `private void CoolMethod(float bla)`) to the incremenentCallback parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This is the definition of `Action`:

```
public delegate void Action();
```

It is a placeholder for a function that returns void and accepts no arguments.

You could use any method or anonymous function / lambda expression that matches its signature.

As an example:

```
StartWaiting(1000f, () => Console.WriteLine("done"));
```

Or another:

```
private void WriteToConsole()
{
    Console.WriteLine("done");
}

StartWaiting(1000f, WriteToConsole);
```

`doneCallback.Invoke();` actually invokes that function, but you could also write this as `doneCallback()`; they are equivalent.

---

Similarly, this is `Action<T>`:

```
public delegate void Action<in T>(T obj);
```

So `Action<float>` is a placeholder for a function that returns void and accepts a single argument of type `float`.

An example:

```
var increments = new List<float>();
StartWaiting(1000f, WriteToConsole, 1f, floats.Add);
```